# Spark write speed performance test while loading data from Teradata to S3 in parquet format

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet, data-partitioning

I have a requirement wherein I need to migrate tables from Teradata to DELL ECS S3, with the data being written in parquet format. I have been given a Spark cluster with single worker node of 1GB size and a driver of 2GB size. I am trying to test the performance of my spark code by using small dataset first: was able to load a table of 0.3GB size to S3. The process took around 1 min 3 secs to finish. This is the best performance that I have achieved for this dataset in which I just fetched the data in single partition, cached and wrote it back in a single partition to S3: had tried partitioning the data at source and target side but all those methods took longer than 1 min 3 secs.

I would like to know if there is a way to improve the performance further, or is this the max I can get for the compute resource that I have at my disposal?

This is roughly the code that I have written for getting it done(pretty straightforward since it's just data lift and shift):

```
df = spark.read.format("jdbc")\
.option("user", "user_name")\
.option("password","pwd")\
.option("url","jdbc:teradata://servername/LOGMECH=TD2")\
.option("driver","com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver")\
.option("query","sql_query_for_source_table").load()

df.cache()

filepath = 's3a://s3_bucket_name/prefix/tablename'

#For S3 write
df.write.mode("overwrite").format("parquet").option("compression","snappy").save(filepath)
```

The code that I used while partitioning at source/tgt level looks like:

```
df = spark.read.format("jdbc")\
.option("user", "user_name")\
.option("password","pwd")\
.option("url","jdbc:teradata://servername/LOGMECH=TD2")\
.option("driver","com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver")\
.option("dbtable","db_name.table_name")\
.option("partitionColumn","Business_Date")\
.option("LowerBound","lowest_value_of_business_date")\
.option("upperBound","highest_value_of_business_date")\
.option("numPartitions","This value was based on different granular level of the business date column, so could be the number of years in the tables or number of quarters or months").load()

df.cache()

#Added another column based on the value given in numPartitions to reduce the number of partitions in dataframe as the data volume is less

tgt_df = df.withColumn("part_col", {logic for extracting the year/month/quarter from Business_date column})
```

```
tgt_df.write.partitionBy("part_col").mode("overwrite").format("parquet").option("compression","snappy").save(filepath)
```

Just to add: Had got values as 4, 31 and 11 while partitioning business date column at yearly, monthly and quarterly level respectively.

Apologies for the long post, just wanted every detail to be mentioned.

Comment: Can you check in `Spark UI` what's taking the most amount of time? I am assuming it might be while writing into S3 and what version of `spark` are you using?

Comment: @Frosty Checked spark UI worker log: the part which takes the most time is the part where the fetch from database happens, it takes roughly a minute. The write part has no delay.  I'm using Spark 3.3.0

Comment: `df.cache()` is basically useless in both cases. In general, Spark achieves its performance by distributing and parallelizing work across multiple executors. With one executor, there is nowhere to distribute to.

Comment: hmm.. How many cores does your worker node have ? and is your Teradata and spark running within AWS?

Comment: @mazaneicha Yes, even I am inclined to that point you mentioned. What I observed is that caching post read operation took around 4 mins of time, so Spark took less time during write. Non-cached approach took around 4.5 mins of time. So in reality, both cached and non-cached approach took roughly the same amount of time.

Comment: @Frosty My worker has a single core. And we are not using AWS services, the DELL ECS S3 servers are on-prem. Teradata runs separately. Basically we are planning to migrate from Teradata in order to cut down the cost involved in storing data in Teradata.

Comment: So I guess you guys too believe that the processing time is bit too much for this dataset, right?

Comment: @the_data_novice `.cache()` is not an action, i.e. it is NOT executed until you call .write(). So, it serves no purpose here other than occupy Spark memory (and disk if memory is not sufficient).

Comment: @Frosty Yes, you are right. I was implying the same in my comment earlier. It doesn't make any difference. Just seeking for something that will :(

Comment: And generally, it makes no real sense to test Spark _performance_ in a single core cluster. Trivial Java/JDBC app will beat Spark hands-down in such configuration.

Comment: @mazaneicha Yes I have already raised this concern with my leads and the infra team. But they insist that such small dataset should not take this much time to process and think that the code is not tuned well, so I am running out of ideas to prove otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to make this faster is to get more worker nodes, and give it more data. Use `.coalesce()` instead of `.repartition()` or `.partitionBy()` to reduce data movement. But with only one worker, the fastest you can get is pretty limited - without parallelism it's just one computer reading one s3 file.

Comment: So what you are trying to tell is that this is probably the max I can get out of this single core worker. Will try out the `.coalesce()` change and see what difference it makes. Regarding allocating more workers, I might need bit more time to get them provisioned, but will post my comments here if I see a difference.